# Stack size in Unix pthread_create

Tags: pthreads

I am creating 10 threads using pthread_create in my application. What is the default stack size assigned to each thread?

I am trying to debug a crash where my application is crashing on an illegal instruction where one of the function pointer is reset to 0. One of the indicator of this can be my application thread has run out of stack size and it overwrote an existing stack space where the function pointer was residing.

Comment: call `pthread_attr_getstacksize` and find out?

Answer (score 1):

See https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/ for a tutorial on pthreads. You set the initial stack size with the `attr` parameter, created with `pthread_attr_init`.  In general, though, you do not want to have a huge stack. If you are allocating more than a few hundred kilobytes on the stack, you may find it easier to debug your program by allocating the data on the heap and freeing it as needed.